# Not able to get Backup of MYSQL Database by Batch File in Windows

Tags: mysql, sql

i wrote following command in a file and made it a Batch File,and after running Batch File i am getting a Blank SQL File.

> mysqldump –u root –proot lakshmimbar > db_test.sql

Comment: open your `Batch File` in `notepad` and in the end of all line write `pause` and run the `batch file` again see what error your getting and show the error here once you can't understand what that error means

Comment: and if your batch file only contains `mysqldump –u root –proot lakshmimbar > db_test.sql` then it wont take backup

Comment: @WingedPanther thanx for reply.if it wont work,then what i need to do take backup of mysql database using batch file..and i have written pause at end but it didn't throw any error..still getting a blank sql file.

Comment: show the entire content inside your `batch file`

Comment: this is the only statement i have written inside Batch file,see i don't have much idea about it,plz tell me if any other thing i need to add.

Comment: first of all you have to locate path of `mysqldump`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example,
if `mysqldump` is located in `D:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump`(in your case the place where you have installed `Mysql` probabily in `C:\Program Files`)

- create a batch file like below

  ```
      cd /D D:\\MySQL
      cd MySQL Server 5.5
      cd bin
      mysqldump -u user -p database > backup_file_name.sql
  ```

  run the script and comment if any error occurs

Comment: its done..thanx a lot for solution..c:\

cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin

mysqldump -u root -proot lakshmibar>C:\lakshmibar.sql